# Reduce overfitting in a CNN model

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, cnn, accuracy, overfitting

We are Data science students and we are building a CNN model to pneumonia classification (dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia ). We have applied a data augmentation for improve our number of images to balance the classes (5500 images for classes).

Data augmentation process is the same for both the classes.

**Data augmentation**

```
import os
import glob
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
```

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range =45,
                             vertical_flip = True,
                             width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                             height_shift_range = 0.2,  
                             rescale=1./255, 
                             shear_range=0.2, 
                             zoom_range=0.2, 
                             zca_whitening= True,
                             horizontal_flip = True, 
                             fill_mode = 'nearest', 
                             data_format='channels_last', 
                             brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])
```

```
%%time

import  cv2
img_dir = 'NORMAL' 
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
for f1 in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f1)
    data.append(img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
```

```
%%time

i = 0
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk("NORMAL"))
file_count = len(files)*8

for batch in datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir ='augmentation',save_prefix="N",save_format='jpg'):
    i+=1
    if i==file_count:
        break
```

```
%%time
#rename NORMAL images

path = '/train/NORMAL'
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path,'NORMAL'+str(i)+'.jpeg'))
        i = i +1
```

**Model**

```
%%time

normal = []
pneumonia = []

img_size = 150

normal_path = ('/content/train/NORMAL')
pneumonia_path = ('/content/train/PNEUMONIA')

DIRS = [(0, normal_path), (1, pneumonia_path)]
```

```
%%time

train_images = []
labels = []
for num, _dir in DIRS:
    _dir = _dir + '/'
    count = 0
    for file in os.listdir(_dir):
        if count >= 5500:
            break
        img = image.load_img(_dir + str(file), target_size=(img_size, img_size))
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
        img = img/255
        train_images.append(img)
        labels.append(num)
        count += 1
```

```
%%time

X = np.array(train_images)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=101)
```

```
y_train_labels = to_categorical(y_train)
```

```
%%time

def build(width, height, depth, classes):
    #initialize the model along with the input shape
    initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=1234) 
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    chanDim = -1
    
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        inputShape = (depth, height, width)
        chanDim = 1  
    
    
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1), input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.10))
    
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.10))
    
    model.add(Convolution2D(16, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.10))
    
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(0.1), ))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.10))

    model.add(Flatten())
   
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    
    return model
```

```
model = build(img_size, img_size, 3, 2)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 150, 150, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 150, 150, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 150, 150, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 75, 75, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 75, 75, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 75, 75, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 75, 75, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 75, 75, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 37, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 37, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 37, 37, 16)        4624      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 37, 37, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 37, 37, 16)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 18, 18, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 18, 18, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 18, 18, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 18, 18, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 18, 18, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 9, 9, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 9, 9, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 2592)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 2)                 5186      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 35,282
Trainable params: 34,994
Non-trainable params: 288
```

```
%%time

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train_labels, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.30)
Epoch 1/100
217/217 [==============================] - 10s 48ms/step - loss: 13.8373 - accuracy: 0.9567 - val_loss: 2.9341 - val_accuracy: 0.4953
Epoch 2/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.9611 - accuracy: 0.9750 - val_loss: 1.4211 - val_accuracy: 0.4953
Epoch 3/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.4153 - accuracy: 0.9785 - val_loss: 0.7272 - val_accuracy: 0.7215
Epoch 4/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.2925 - accuracy: 0.9799 - val_loss: 0.9268 - val_accuracy: 0.7037
Epoch 5/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.2749 - accuracy: 0.9818 - val_loss: 0.3339 - val_accuracy: 0.9576
Epoch 6/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.2414 - accuracy: 0.9814 - val_loss: 0.2825 - val_accuracy: 0.9384
Epoch 7/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.2163 - accuracy: 0.9831 - val_loss: 0.9659 - val_accuracy: 0.8202
Epoch 8/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.2122 - accuracy: 0.9834 - val_loss: 0.2410 - val_accuracy: 0.9727
Epoch 9/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.2188 - accuracy: 0.9830 - val_loss: 0.3082 - val_accuracy: 0.9815
Epoch 10/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.2107 - accuracy: 0.9844 - val_loss: 0.2320 - val_accuracy: 0.9684
Epoch 11/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.2385 - accuracy: 0.9814 - val_loss: 0.2697 - val_accuracy: 0.9677
Epoch 12/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1806 - accuracy: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.4971 - val_accuracy: 0.9027
Epoch 13/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1647 - accuracy: 0.9841 - val_loss: 2.6447 - val_accuracy: 0.6088
Epoch 14/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1710 - accuracy: 0.9851 - val_loss: 0.2097 - val_accuracy: 0.9660
Epoch 15/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1781 - accuracy: 0.9841 - val_loss: 0.3810 - val_accuracy: 0.9189
Epoch 16/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1466 - accuracy: 0.9877 - val_loss: 0.2020 - val_accuracy: 0.9785
Epoch 17/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1622 - accuracy: 0.9843 - val_loss: 0.1882 - val_accuracy: 0.9731
Epoch 18/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1468 - accuracy: 0.9850 - val_loss: 0.3029 - val_accuracy: 0.9556
Epoch 19/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1536 - accuracy: 0.9846 - val_loss: 0.2355 - val_accuracy: 0.9458
Epoch 20/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1456 - accuracy: 0.9853 - val_loss: 0.1792 - val_accuracy: 0.9798
Epoch 21/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1371 - accuracy: 0.9863 - val_loss: 0.1802 - val_accuracy: 0.9832
Epoch 22/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1378 - accuracy: 0.9847 - val_loss: 0.7035 - val_accuracy: 0.9135
Epoch 23/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1446 - accuracy: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.3637 - val_accuracy: 0.8973
Epoch 24/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1193 - accuracy: 0.9861 - val_loss: 0.1854 - val_accuracy: 0.9609
Epoch 25/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1284 - accuracy: 0.9859 - val_loss: 0.1862 - val_accuracy: 0.9717
Epoch 26/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1377 - accuracy: 0.9814 - val_loss: 0.5382 - val_accuracy: 0.8960
Epoch 27/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1266 - accuracy: 0.9834 - val_loss: 0.1324 - val_accuracy: 0.9835
Epoch 28/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1200 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.1707 - val_accuracy: 0.9774
Epoch 29/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1178 - accuracy: 0.9846 - val_loss: 0.1559 - val_accuracy: 0.9707
Epoch 30/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1112 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.1294 - val_accuracy: 0.9825
Epoch 31/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1152 - accuracy: 0.9848 - val_loss: 0.1786 - val_accuracy: 0.9586
Epoch 32/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1050 - accuracy: 0.9877 - val_loss: 0.1276 - val_accuracy: 0.9835
Epoch 33/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1010 - accuracy: 0.9883 - val_loss: 0.1495 - val_accuracy: 0.9630
Epoch 34/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1024 - accuracy: 0.9880 - val_loss: 1.3460 - val_accuracy: 0.6687
Epoch 35/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1046 - accuracy: 0.9876 - val_loss: 0.3186 - val_accuracy: 0.9431
Epoch 36/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.1058 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.1845 - val_accuracy: 0.9576
Epoch 37/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1041 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.1200 - val_accuracy: 0.9845
Epoch 38/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1053 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.7715 - val_accuracy: 0.7919
Epoch 39/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1013 - accuracy: 0.9877 - val_loss: 0.1210 - val_accuracy: 0.9832
Epoch 40/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0997 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.2194 - val_accuracy: 0.9478
Epoch 41/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1045 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.1183 - val_accuracy: 0.9828
Epoch 42/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0991 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.1148 - val_accuracy: 0.9852
Epoch 43/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0876 - accuracy: 0.9899 - val_loss: 0.1446 - val_accuracy: 0.9657
Epoch 44/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0881 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.9434
Epoch 45/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0900 - accuracy: 0.9870 - val_loss: 0.2228 - val_accuracy: 0.9377
Epoch 46/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0905 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.1515 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 47/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1060 - accuracy: 0.9853 - val_loss: 0.1051 - val_accuracy: 0.9838
Epoch 48/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0887 - accuracy: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.1118 - val_accuracy: 0.9761
Epoch 49/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0879 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.1649 - val_accuracy: 0.9566
Epoch 50/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0941 - accuracy: 0.9848 - val_loss: 0.1305 - val_accuracy: 0.9747
Epoch 51/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0868 - accuracy: 0.9893 - val_loss: 0.1722 - val_accuracy: 0.9667
Epoch 52/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0856 - accuracy: 0.9877 - val_loss: 0.2049 - val_accuracy: 0.9418
Epoch 53/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0930 - accuracy: 0.9867 - val_loss: 0.1377 - val_accuracy: 0.9771
Epoch 54/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0893 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.1309 - val_accuracy: 0.9788
Epoch 55/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0945 - accuracy: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.1205 - val_accuracy: 0.9828
Epoch 56/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0881 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.1288 - val_accuracy: 0.9825
Epoch 57/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0944 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.5726 - val_accuracy: 0.8613
Epoch 58/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1009 - accuracy: 0.9846 - val_loss: 0.1765 - val_accuracy: 0.9572
Epoch 59/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0916 - accuracy: 0.9886 - val_loss: 0.1366 - val_accuracy: 0.9737
Epoch 60/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0858 - accuracy: 0.9890 - val_loss: 0.1202 - val_accuracy: 0.9764
Epoch 61/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0853 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.1848 - val_accuracy: 0.9515
Epoch 62/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0997 - accuracy: 0.9861 - val_loss: 0.3633 - val_accuracy: 0.9165
Epoch 63/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1011 - accuracy: 0.9882 - val_loss: 0.1214 - val_accuracy: 0.9751
Epoch 64/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0848 - accuracy: 0.9892 - val_loss: 0.2118 - val_accuracy: 0.9471
Epoch 65/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0907 - accuracy: 0.9883 - val_loss: 0.1917 - val_accuracy: 0.9579
Epoch 66/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0883 - accuracy: 0.9893 - val_loss: 0.1620 - val_accuracy: 0.9741
Epoch 67/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0906 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.1543 - val_accuracy: 0.9727
Epoch 68/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0873 - accuracy: 0.9905 - val_loss: 0.3044 - val_accuracy: 0.9246
Epoch 69/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0902 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.1103 - val_accuracy: 0.9811
Epoch 70/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0888 - accuracy: 0.9892 - val_loss: 0.1271 - val_accuracy: 0.9808
Epoch 71/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0954 - accuracy: 0.9874 - val_loss: 0.1114 - val_accuracy: 0.9862
Epoch 72/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0890 - accuracy: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.4402 - val_accuracy: 0.8902
Epoch 73/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0858 - accuracy: 0.9887 - val_loss: 0.2590 - val_accuracy: 0.9401
Epoch 74/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0833 - accuracy: 0.9903 - val_loss: 0.1798 - val_accuracy: 0.9529
Epoch 75/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0890 - accuracy: 0.9882 - val_loss: 0.2340 - val_accuracy: 0.9529
Epoch 76/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0861 - accuracy: 0.9902 - val_loss: 0.1544 - val_accuracy: 0.9663
Epoch 77/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0857 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.1358 - val_accuracy: 0.9747
Epoch 78/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0846 - accuracy: 0.9896 - val_loss: 0.1611 - val_accuracy: 0.9613
Epoch 79/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0838 - accuracy: 0.9909 - val_loss: 0.1216 - val_accuracy: 0.9744
Epoch 80/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.1234 - accuracy: 0.9834 - val_loss: 0.1747 - val_accuracy: 0.9640
Epoch 81/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0929 - accuracy: 0.9876 - val_loss: 0.1156 - val_accuracy: 0.9811
Epoch 82/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0813 - accuracy: 0.9903 - val_loss: 0.1233 - val_accuracy: 0.9815
Epoch 83/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0801 - accuracy: 0.9912 - val_loss: 0.1104 - val_accuracy: 0.9791
Epoch 84/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0790 - accuracy: 0.9909 - val_loss: 0.1446 - val_accuracy: 0.9677
Epoch 85/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0863 - accuracy: 0.9887 - val_loss: 0.1100 - val_accuracy: 0.9842
Epoch 86/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0815 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.1410 - val_accuracy: 0.9818
Epoch 87/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0848 - accuracy: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.1438 - val_accuracy: 0.9704
Epoch 88/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0941 - accuracy: 0.9873 - val_loss: 0.1201 - val_accuracy: 0.9774
Epoch 89/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0863 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.1199 - val_accuracy: 0.9835
Epoch 90/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0794 - accuracy: 0.9909 - val_loss: 0.1292 - val_accuracy: 0.9785
Epoch 91/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0789 - accuracy: 0.9906 - val_loss: 0.2260 - val_accuracy: 0.9492
Epoch 92/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0904 - accuracy: 0.9886 - val_loss: 0.1604 - val_accuracy: 0.9640
Epoch 93/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0773 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.1194 - val_accuracy: 0.9822
Epoch 94/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0799 - accuracy: 0.9911 - val_loss: 0.2213 - val_accuracy: 0.9465
Epoch 95/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0835 - accuracy: 0.9911 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_accuracy: 0.9828
Epoch 96/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0999 - accuracy: 0.9866 - val_loss: 0.1114 - val_accuracy: 0.9845
Epoch 97/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0880 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.1255 - val_accuracy: 0.9741
Epoch 98/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0848 - accuracy: 0.9908 - val_loss: 0.1314 - val_accuracy: 0.9818
Epoch 99/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0776 - accuracy: 0.9924 - val_loss: 0.1916 - val_accuracy: 0.9532
Epoch 100/100
217/217 [==============================] - 9s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0870 - accuracy: 0.9896 - val_loss: 0.1198 - val_accuracy: 0.9852
```

```
%%time

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy LR=0.0005')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss LR=0.0005')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Accuracy Model graph]
[image: Loss Model graph]

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.98      0.99      0.98       567
           1       0.99      0.98      0.98       533

    accuracy                           0.98      1100
   macro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      1100
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      1100
```

However, when testing the model on a never-before-seen dataset, the accuracy of the model turns out to be much lower than that predicted by the model (real 70-75%, instead of 98%).

How can we improve the fit accuracy of the model? As can be seen from the loss graph, the fit on the loss is very good, but the accuracy graph shows overfit. We tried to limit overfit using regularizer (L1 and L2), Dropout, Batchnormalization, Learning rate and testing a lot of optimizer and model architecture. But all tries failed to improve the accuracy on test set

Comment: 1. Change the Order of "Augmentation-->Split" to Split-->Augmentation(train only). 2. Try Class_weight too.

Comment: 3. Check that you are not using the same patient in the train, val and test datasets. Otherwise your model can learn person_101 -> sick, rather then the actual logic. 4. Do not use augmentations that does not reflect images that you would typically find in "real conditions -> the test dataset' " e.g. flipping images. 5. Might want to try one neuron in your final layer instead of two (easier to update + metrics will be easier to interpret)